# Using Loop to Get Drink Total

Tags: javascript, html, loops

Currently I am using a function like this to get the total of each drink, in which there are 5 drinks total:

```
var totalEstimate = 0;
var locoCost = 0;
var blackCost = 0;

function calcLoco() {
                totalEstimate -= locoCost;
                locoCost = document.drinkList.quant2.value * price[1];
                totalEstimate += locoCost;
                document.drinkList.order.value = "$" + totalEstimate;
            }

function calcBlack() {
                totalEstimate -= blackCost;
                blackCost = document.drinkList.quant1.value * price[0];
                totalEstimate += blackCost;
                document.drinkList.order.value = "$" + totalEstimate;
            }
```

What I want to do is instead of having 5 functions like the one above, to just have 1 loop function that will look through all 5 text boxes for the quantity of each drink, and get the total based off of the drink prices (in which I have stored in an Array), and based off of the quantity of the drinks they ordered. Could anyone point me in the right direction please? Thanks

Comment: Google is a search engine, I think they'll become really big in the future, try it - it will give you stuff like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Answer (score 0):

I would check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Basically you want to use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // Calculate loco
}
```